# Crystal Report same parameter in different commands

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

I have to use same parameter(paramCompanyId) in both the commands.

I will be setting the parameter value on code.

```
crystalReportDocument.SetParameterValue("paramCompanyId",LoggedInMembersCompanyID);
```

[image]
Note:

- command:crmleadsbycustomer  =>  retrieves report data
- command:crmopportunity => dynamic filter dropdown data

Issues:

- If I use the same parameter it keeps on prompting without executing
  the report.
- I don’t want user to enter parameter on prompt so I am setting up in
  code.
- I don’t want to use separate parameters for each command (this way
  works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Edit parameter and change the list of values to "Dynamic" and under "Value", choose the companyID column from command "crmopportunity". 
Create a new formula: {?paramCompanyId}=companyID column from command "crmleadsbycustomer".
In the Record Select Expert, use this formula to filter the records.